# Why is $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac i n\right)^{1.5} =\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x} \,dx$?

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Evaluate $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n} \left(\frac i n\right)^{1.5} $$

The solution says this is a Riemann sum for $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x} \,dx$, but I do not understand how they converted the above sum to the definite integral.

Comment: My answer here gives a bit of a general idea: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2355382/171839

Comment: Write down the upper Riemann sum for said integral with the partition $x_i=\frac in$, $0\le i\le n$

Comment: But since the integral is from 0 to 1, wouldn't I need to take out a (1/n) factor?

Answer (score 1):

As written, the limit does not exist.  Call that sum $S_n$ for a given value of $n$.  Then $S_{100} \approx 40.5, S_{1000} \approx 400.5$ by direct computation.  One way to see that the limit doesn't exist is as follows:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^n \left( {i\over n} \right)^{1.5} > \sum_{i=n/2}^n \left( {i\over n} \right)^{1.5} > \sum_{i=n/2}^n \left( {n/2 \over n} \right)^{1.5} $$

where the first inequality comes by omitting some positive terms, and the second one since $i\ge n/2$ for all terms in that sum and $i>n/2$ for at least one term.  But the sum is clearly $(n+1) (1/2)^{1.5}$.  So we have $S_n > n/\sqrt{8}$.

On the other hand each term in the sum is less than or equal to 1 so $S_n \le n+1$.

If you insert a $1/n$ out front you have a Riemann sum and you have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {1 \over n} \sum_{i=0}^n \left( {i \over n} \right)^{1.5} = \int_0^1 x^{1.5} dx = 2/5$$

which is probably what the problem is "supposed to" be.  And in fact $S_n \approx 2n/5$.

Comment: How does $ \sum_{i=n/2}^n \left( {n/2 \over n} \right)^{1.5}=(n+1) (1/2)^{1.5}?$ and how did you come to the conclusion that $S_{n}<n$?

Comment: For the first question, every term in that sum is $(1/2)^{1.5}$ and there are $n+1$ of them.  For the second question, since $i \le n$ in each term of the sum, each term is less than or equal to $1$ and there are $n+1$ of them; strictly speaking this only shows $S_n \le n+1$.  I've edited accordingly for the second question.

Comment: I thought there were n-n/2=n/2 (1/2)^1.5 terms?

Answer (score 0):

The given limit is diverging. Since $x^{3/2}$ is a Riemann-integrable function over $[0,1]$ we have
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3/2} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{3/2}\,dx = \frac{2}{5} $$
hence $\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^{3/2} $ behaves like $\frac{2}{5} n^{5/2}$.

Comment: The solution says the answer is 2/3, but in the errata it corrected it to "none of the above," so would the correct answer be diverges?

Comment: @chrismc: $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{3/2}$ roughly has a linear grow as $n\to +\infty$, its limit cannot be $\frac{2}{3}$. Probably a typo in the original text - it is $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^{1/2} $$ that equals $\frac{2}{3}$.